# Sfml Sprite not showing

Tags: c++, class, object, game-development, sfml

I'm new to sfml and was trying to create a class characters to create player whose sprite is stuck with its bounding box, but its not working properly

i tried to check by switching the sf::Sprite to sf::RectangleShape to see if shape is loading so that i can see if there is problem with my function and there is problem with my function. Idk where I'm doing wrong

```
#pragma once
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
class Characters
{
   public:
       Characters();
       sf::FloatRect createBoundingBox(float posX, float posY, float width, float height);
       void updateBoundingBox(sf::FloatRect& boundingBox, float posX, float posY, float width, float height);
       sf::Sprite CharacterSprite(sf::FloatRect boundingBox, std::string filelocation);
       void updateSpritePosition(sf::Sprite& m_sprite,sf::FloatRect boundingBox);
       sf::RectangleShape createShape(sf::FloatRect& boundingBox);
   private:
       sf::Texture mtexture;
};
```

```
#include "Characters.h"
#include<iostream>
Characters::Characters() {
}
sf::FloatRect Characters::createBoundingBox(float posX, float posY, float width, float height) {
    sf::FloatRect boundingBox;
    boundingBox.left = posX;
    boundingBox.top = posY;
    boundingBox.width = width;
    boundingBox.height = height;
    return boundingBox;
}
sf::RectangleShape Characters::createShape(sf::FloatRect& boundingBox) {
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle;
    rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(boundingBox.width, boundingBox.height));
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    rectangle.setOrigin(sf::Vector2f(boundingBox.left, boundingBox.top));
    return rectangle;

}
void Characters::updateBoundingBox(sf::FloatRect& boundingBox,float posX, float posY, float width, float height) {
    boundingBox.left = posX;
    boundingBox.top = posY;
    boundingBox.width = width;
    boundingBox.height = height;
}
sf::Sprite Characters::CharacterSprite(sf::FloatRect boundingBox, std::string filelocation) {
    if (!mtexture.loadFromFile(filelocation)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load texture from file: " + filelocation);
    }
    sf::Sprite newSprite;
    newSprite.setTexture(mtexture);
    newSprite.setPosition(boundingBox.left, boundingBox.top);
    newSprite.setScale(boundingBox.width, boundingBox.height);
    return newSprite;
}
void Characters::updateSpritePosition(sf::Sprite& m_sprite,sf::FloatRect boundingBox) {
    m_sprite.setPosition(boundingBox.left, boundingBox.top);
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include "Characters.h"
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    sf::RectangleShape getPlayer();
    
private:
    Characters main;
    sf::Sprite mainPlayer;
    sf::FloatRect mainBoundingBox;
    sf::RectangleShape playerBox;
};

#include "Player.h"
#include "Characters.h"
Player::Player() {
    sf::FloatRect mainBoundingBox = main.createBoundingBox(100,50,2000,2000);
    sf::Sprite mainPlayer = main.CharacterSprite(mainBoundingBox, ".\\textures\\player.png");
    sf::RectangleShape playerBox = main.createShape(mainBoundingBox);
    
}
sf::RectangleShape Player::getPlayer() {
    return playerBox;
}
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/Window.hpp>
#include "Player.h"
class Windows {
public:
    Windows();
    void gameLoop();
    Player player;

private:
    sf::RenderWindow m_Window;
    sf::Event m_Event;
};
```

```
#include "Windows.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include<SFML/Window.hpp>

Windows::Windows() : m_Window(sf::VideoMode(1800, 1000), "Project_Dark") {
 
}

void Windows::gameLoop() {
    sf::RectangleShape m_player = player.getPlayer();
    while (m_Window.isOpen()) {
        while (m_Window.pollEvent(m_Event)) {
            if (m_Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                m_Window.close();
        }

        m_Window.clear();
        m_Window.draw(m_player);
        m_Window.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: `sf::FloatRect mainBoundingBox = `  creates a *local* variable instead of initializing a member with same name. Initialize members at initializer list: `Player::Player(): mainBoundingBox { main.createBoundingBox(100,50,2000,2000)} ...`

Comment: In order to find your issue you should start with a less complex code structure. When the basics (like drawing a sprite) work as expected within a simple main-loop you may afterwards go for sophisticated classes and data structures.
Without understanding your whole approach, I can at least see one clear bug:    `newSprite.setScale(boundingBox.width, boundingBox.height);` is nonsense. setScale expects scaling factors e.g. `{1.f,1.f}` for no scaling, `{0.5f,0.5f}` for halve the size, `{2.f,2.f}` for doubling the size. Providing the dimensions of the box here will not work.